# Powershell: Output Variables passed from Manage Engine

Tags: powershell, variables, output

I'm having some issues with making some changes to an existing working script I have, but I have run into an issue with some variables that are being passed from my Manage Engine Software.

In order to better understand what the issue is i'm attempting to devise a simple script to output the variables to a text file so I can see what Manage Engine is spitting out for certain variables.  However the script seems to fail when attempting to execute.

Here is what I am using in an attempt to get to the bottom of this.

Command:

```
Param(
[string]$Department
)

$Filepath = "\\fileserver\filename.txt"

$Department | out-file -filepath $filepath
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell without an error message, but it's most likely permissions on the share. Try writing to a file on a local disk with loose permissions.

Comment: pipe the output from Manage Engine to `Get-Member` instead

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mathias comment with ValueFromRemainingArguments:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [psobject[]]$InputObject
)

$InputObject | Get-Member
```